# Urls parameters conflict in ajax calls

Tags: django, url

Before submitting a form I perform multiple ajax requests according to user's inputs. The problem is that two urls match in the number and types of the parameters I pass that results  a wrong view to be called. What I mean:

```
url(r'^main_Webrequests/(?P<d>\d+)/(?P<m>\d+)/(?P<y>\d+)/$', 'auth.views.get_dates', name='get_dates'),
```

where I get the input date and

```
url(r'^main_Webrequests/(?P<veh_id1>\d+)/(?P<veh_id2>\d+)/(?P<load_id>\d+)/$', 'auth.views.get_initialVehicles', name='initialVehicles'),
```

where I get other inputs.

With the dates(1st call) everything works fine, but since django checks the urls from the first to the last one when the ajax call gets the parameters for the second url(2nd call) it calls get_dates and the functionality fails.
Is there a way to fix it or maybe my whole logic is wrong?

Comment: Change `main_Webrequests` part of your url to specific for each view. I would do `url(r'get_dates/....', 'auth.views.get_dates' ...)` and `url(r'get_initVehicals/....', 'auth.views.get_initialVehicles' ...)`

Comment: I should change much stuff by doing this. Everything to be 'under' main_Webrequests, so this solution doesn't fit me I think.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your urls, so they can differ from each other. For now you have two equal url patterns, so all requests go into first view. Or you can divide logic into a view. For example:

```
...
perform auth.views.get_dates logic
...
if request.is_ajax():
   perform some auth.views.get_initialVehicles logic
```